# calculate value of $2^{3^{4^{5}}}/e^{10240}$

Tags: power-towers

I am trying to calculate the value of $b=\dfrac{2^{3^{4^5}}}{e^{10240}}$.
Is there any method to solve this efficiently?

Comment: Do you prioritize the exponents or the base in the power-tower?

Comment: yes, the exponents is prioritize top down, that is 2^(3^(4^5)). I want to find out a numerical method to calculate the value with enough accuracy.

Comment: Is there more context for this problem? Is this homework for a class or a question you have made up?

Comment: This comes from a students in physics class and he asked me this. He said he want to estimate the number of electrons from an emission. Actually I don't know very clearly how this number is derived. So I post here to see if anyone can give me some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see [*WolframAlpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E3%5E4%5E5%2Fe%5E1024) can give you an approximative power of 10 representation:
$$10^{10^{10^{2.688465006395752}}}.$$

It is hard to get a better solution, because this number is too large. To show it, we will calculate the number of digits in base-$10$ representation. If $n$ is a number in base-$b$, with $d$ digits, then we [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-log-10-n-1), that the formula for $d$ is the following:
$$d=\lfloor\log_{b}n\rfloor+1.$$
Now let $$n:=\dfrac{2^{3^{4^5}}}{e^{10240}}.$$
Then the number of digits of $n$ in base-$10$ is
$$d = \lfloor \log_{10} \dfrac{2^{3^{4^5}}}{e^{10240}}\rfloor+1 \\
d = \lfloor \log_{10} 2^{3^{4^5}} - \log_{10} e^{10240}\rfloor+1 \\
d = \lfloor 3^{4^5} \cdot \log_{10} 2 - 10240 \cdot \log_{10} e\rfloor+1.$$

We get the following for $d$:

> $1124021466074751860097567522104789648012545442387518261576295420518 \\5174447660807915950553426138321488548657928846792570107753324167422 \\0100211779337007726069891241143955562498313809792175538301726950271 \\2513614070749429457547548532111853109636637797579524872247171419406 \\3487219461564568491620652987627661309480232956516340085351404053765 \\2037205369420431855146383193275981445894731731211119067826441631620 \\7609542700946643046958255703325110043123352486373327969799306832787 \\29227794366058969345$

So $n$ has $1.2402146607475186 \cdot 10^{489}$ digits.

You can easily check the result  with [*Maple*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)):

```
floor(3^(4^5)*log10(2)-10240*log10(exp(1)))+1;
```

This $n$ number is larger then a [*googleplex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googolplex), which number also doesn't have a base-$10$ representation, because that is also too large. On the other hand this is less then [*Skewes' number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27_number) and much much less then [*Graham's number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number). Read more at [*Large numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers) wikipedia article.

The problem is that $2^{3^{4^5}}$ is too large. It is much larger then the denominator. The numerator and the whole fraction have just $4$ [*order of magnitude*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) difference in base-$10$, the difference of the lengths is $4447$. The above give approximation has $1.124020417 \cdot 10^{489}$ digits, so the real value and the approximation has $1.049 \cdot 10^{483}$ difference in the numbers of digits.

Comment: Thank you user153012. After your analysis I realize the number is too large to be estimated with desired accuracy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E3%5E4%5E5%2Fe%5E10240) for the question in the title, or [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E3%5E4%5E5%2Fe%5E10240) for the one in the body.  Either one is enormous.