# Relation between number of digits of a number and its logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

I found a couple of questions where, for example, they ask you to calculate the number of digits in $18^{200}$ and only the value of $\log 18$ is given. Can anyone tell me a way?

Comment: Assuming the logarithm is in base 10, if you take the log of any number in base 10 and round it up, you will get the number of digits in that number.

Comment: The number of decimal digits in $N$ would be $\lfloor \log_{10} N \rfloor+1$.

Comment: Log of a number returns approximately the number of digits. Log 1=0, log 10=1, log 100=2 etc. Log(18^200) = 200.log(18).

Comment: Can you guys tell me how we get this result?

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 5):

It is not too tough to find the # of digits in $200\times\ log_{10}(18)$ = 251.05...

You might recall that the integer portion of the logarithm is called the *characteristic*, and the decimal part, the *mantissa*

You would also recall that: log(10) = 1, and  the logarithm remains less than 2 as long as N<100, log(100) = 2, and so on.

The simple rule that emerges is: *Add 1 to the characteristic* to get the # of digits in the *number*.

Or, in briefer mathematical notation, using the *floor* function, D = $\lfloor \log_{10} N \rfloor+1$

Comment: How do we get this result?

Comment: You should know the basic rules of logs ! log($a\cdot b) = log(a) + log(b), log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b), and log$(a^b)$ = b*log(a)

Comment: Exactly how does the number of digits in $200\times \log 18$ answer the problem? That's wrong.

Comment: @Macavity:Sorry, misread, have made the adjustment.