# finding out total digits in a large number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is there any easy way to find out how many digits does the number $12^{400}$ have or such types of problems like how many digits the number $x^y$ have? ($x$ and $y$ are variables)

Comment: For $x$, take the integer ceiling of $\log_{10} x$, or the floor of $\log_{10}x + 1$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1/231745#231745). But can't say if it is easy to you or not, because, the definition of *easy* varies over people.

Comment: try a few examples. What is $\log_{10} 1000$? of 1,000,000$? of 1,000,000,000?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ and $y$ aren’t *too* awfully large, you can simply calculate $\log_{10}x^y=y\log_{10}x$. For example,

$$\log_{10}12^{400}=400\log_{10}12\approx431.6725\;,$$

which tells you that the number has $431+1=432$ digits in base ten.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can calculate the number of digits in an arbitrary base $n$ of an expression $a^b$ by the formula $$D = \lfloor 1 + \log_{n}(a^b)\rfloor = \lfloor 1 + (b)\log_{n}(a)\rfloor$$ where $D$ represents the number of digits in your result.

Comment: can you please tell me the detailed process of  deduction of D? @Owain West

Comment: @user355702 $D$ represents the number of (base $n$ - in your case, the base is 10 since you're talking about decimal numbers) digits in the number. The $\log_n$ of a number can be viewed as a function mapping any number to the a real that is close to the number of digits that it takes to express that number in base $n$.  The adding 1 and floor convert the result of the $\log_n$, which is a real number, into the integer which represents the actual number of digits.

Comment: @user355702 $\log_{10}(12345)=4.09149$ because $10^{4.019149}=12345$.  Furthermore, since $\log_{10}(12345)=4.09$, rounding up gives us $4.09\to5$, which means $12345$ has $5$ digits.  For the case $x^y$, we can just use $y\times\log_{10}(x)$ and round up to find the number of digits.