# Size of the $k$-th prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

Is it possible to give an estimation (maybe an approximation) of the size of the $k$-th prime number?

Comment: Yes, google prime-number-theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem $p_n \sim n \ln n $

Comment: $$p_n\approx n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n)))$$ is a rough estimation

Comment: The OP obviously meant the $k$-th **smallest** prime number.

Comment: are we talking about the size in terms or quantity of digits in base $10$? i.e. the $10^{th}$ prime number is $31$ and its length is $2$ in base $10$. In that case, it is near to $\lfloor\log_{10}(n \cdot ln(n))\rfloor+1$ as per this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1

Comment: @iadvd Thank you for your comments. I am interested by the binary size of primes.

Comment: @Adam54 then if I am not wrong, the lenght in binary should be bounded by $\lfloor log_2 (n \cdot ln(n)) \rfloor + 1$ assuming that we are bounding the $n^{th}$ prime by $n \cdot ln(n)$ (it is a rough estimation).