# Proof that the number of digits in a whole number is $\lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor + 1$

Tags: proof-writing, integers

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then the length $\ell(n)$ of $n$, that is, the number of digits in the decimal representation of $n$, is given by
$$\ell(n) = \lfloor \log_{10}(n)\rfloor + 1.$$
How can one go about *rigorously* proving that this holds for all positive integers?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1?rq=1

Comment: 1) Use division algorithm to prove that for any $n$ there is a unique set of $(a_0,.... a_m)$ so that $a_i$ is a integer between 0 and 9 and $a_m \ne 0$ and $n = \sum a_i*10^i$. 2) By definition, $n$ has $m+1$ digits. 3) Note $10^m \le n < 10^{m+1}$ so $m \le \log_{10} n \le m+1$. 4) That's all.  1) is the rigorous but straightforward part.

Comment: To be fair, none of the answers on the original page are "rigorous".  However I want to point out that proving the number of digits is $[\log_{10} n] + 1$ is trivial.  The hypothesis requiring rigor is actually not that, but that all positive integers *can* actually be expressed uniquely as a base 10 numeral with a specific and distinct number of digits.... although "rigor" is a relative term.  Archemediam property proves the division thereom, and the division th. and induction prove decimal notation is valid.

Comment: Archemedian Property says for any real $M$ and any $y > 0$ there is a unique integer $n$ so that $ny \le M < (n+1)y$ and as a consequence.  $0\le M-ny < y$.  Use induction with $y=10^k$ for integer values of $k$ recursively, and that proves that all positive integers have a unique base 10 representation with a specific number of digits.  If $m$ is that number $10^m \le n <10^{m+1}$ and taking logs, completes the proof.

Comment: And there are several ways to prove the Archemdian Property. Leting $\{n|ny \le M; n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is bounded above by $M/y$ so least upper bound exists, must be an integer, and the sup satisfies and is the solution, is probably the best.