# How many digits in $2^{738}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many digits in $2^{738}-1$. I don't exactly know how to approach this problem. Could the expression somehow be rewritten in the form $a*10^{n-1}$, where $n$ would be the number of digits?

Comment: $\lceil 738\cdot\log_{10}2\rceil=223$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1) help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a$ has $n $ digits $\iff 10^{n-1}\le a<10^n\iff n-1\le \log_{10} a\lt n\iff n-1=\lfloor \log_{10}a\rfloor$

$\iff n=\lfloor \log_{10}a\rfloor+1.$

Therefore, the number of digits of $2^{738}$ is $\lfloor 738\log_{10}2\rfloor+1$, which can be calculated to be $223$.

$a$ has the same number of digits as $a-1$, unless $a$ is a power of $10$, which $2^{738}$ clearly is not.