# How many digits does $n^n$ have?

Tags: number-theory

Say $n$ has $N$ digits and $n^n$ has $N'$ digits, then 
$$10^{N-1}\leq n \lt 10^N$$
$$\implies n(N-1)\leq n\log n \lt nN$$
$$\implies N' \in [n(N-1),nN)$$

Is it possible to round this down further in terms of elementary functions as an expression relating $N$ and $N'$(or $n$ and $n^n$)?

Comment: Any integer $k$ has $\lfloor\log_{10}k\rfloor+1$. Is this a satisfactory answer for you?

Comment: [Proof: How many digits does a number have? $\lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor +1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742)

Answer (score 1):

We know that the number of digits for a positive integer $x$ is simply $\lfloor \log_{10} x \rfloor +1$. We then have:
$$\text{Number of digits in $n^n$} = \lfloor\log_{10} n^n \rfloor+1 = \lfloor n\log_{10} n \rfloor+1$$
However, if you are trying to relate the number of digits in $n$ with the above, your interval is the best you can get, since you have no other information about $n$.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: @jamie As I said above, you cannot get a tight bound for $N'$ in terms of $N$. My answer above gives the precise number of digits that $n^n$ has in terms of $n$.