# Finding the limit of $\frac{N_n}{\ln(n)}$ where $N_n$ is the number of digits of $n$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I came across this question in an entrance exam of a local college where we are asked to evaluate the limit : $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{N_n}{\ln(n)}$$
Where $N_n$ denotes the number of digits of $n$, with the latter being a non zero positive integer.
It seems I am lacking some sort of relationship between $N_n$ and $n$ (i.e equality/inequality). I could spot that $n \ge N_n$ but it doesn't seem useful in this case.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: Hint:  try to relate $N_n$ to $\log_{10}n$.

Comment: @lulu can I just say, your comment game is *on point*

Comment: @Integrand  It's odd to think about which skills are enhanced by extended lockdown, and which deteriorate.  Best to focus on the former, I find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Following the suggestion given in the comments, we have that

$$\frac{\log_{10}n}{\ln(n)}\le \frac{N_n}{\ln(n)}\le \frac{1+\log_{10}n}{\ln(n)}$$

then we can conclude by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! one question: to show that inequality should I start with the expression of $n$ in base $10$ ? like $208=2.10^2+0.10^1+8.10^0$ ? or is there a simpler way ?

Comment: @OUCHNA You are welcome. For more details you can also refer to [that OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231742/505767).

Comment: $100\le 208<1000$ so between $10^2$ and $10^3$. Then notice all numbers $100..999<10^3$  all have $3$ digits.