# Regarding the number of digits of a given number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

After looking for the number of digits of a given number, I found this [Brilliant page](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finding-digits-of-a-number/) that says that given an integer $n$, one can determine $j$, the number of digits in $n$, by working with the inequality $10^{j - 1} \leq n \leq 10^{j} - 1$. By taking the base $10$ logarithm, $j - 1 \leq \log_{10} n < j$, so that $j - 1 = \lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor$.

What I actually don't understand is the **change of signs** from $n \leq 10^{j} - 1$ to $\log_{10} n < j$ and the passage $j - 1 \leq \log_{10} n$ to $j - 1 = \lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor$. I also read the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231742/proof-how-many-digits-does-a-number-have-lfloor-log-10-n-rfloor-1) in the forum but the inequalities are slighty different from the ones of Brilliant. Could you help me out? (Sorry if the questions is ill-posed or confusing)

Comment: $$10^{j-1}\le n\le 10^j-1\lt 10^j\iff j-1\leq\log_{10}n\lt j$$ Since $\log_{10}n$ is not an integer when $n$ is not a power of $10$, you take the floor function to convert it to the greatest integer less than or equal to $\log_{10}n$ and equate it with $j-1$

Comment: If $n\le 10^j-1$, then $n<10^j$, and therefore $\log_{10}n<j$. Then we have $$j-1\le\log_{10}n<j\,,$$ where $j-1$ and $j$ are consecutive integers, so clearly $j-1$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $\log_{10}n$, or inn symbols, $\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor=j-1$.

Comment: The inequalities in my old answer to which you linked are actually the same as the ones at Brilliant, apart from the fact that I used $d$ rather than $j$ and went immediately to $n<10^d$ instead of bothering with $n\le 10^k-1$, since the two are clearly equivalent for integer $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thank you for your comment. After giving it some thought, now I understand the manipulations.

Comment: Thank you very much, @PrasunBiswas.

Comment: @RaphaelFerreira: You’re very welcome.